# Issue with delegate.BeginInvoke and UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

In a button click event (forms control) I have:

```
Action<SomeType, CallbackType> action = (__o1, __callback) =>
{
  __o1.Operation(__callback);
};
action.BeginInvoke(
  o1, 
  callback,
  (asyncCallback) => 
    ((Action<SomeType, CallbackType>)asyncCallback.AsyncState).EndInvoke(asyncCallback),
  action);
```

For some unknown reason the UI thread hangs until this async call returns. But still the click event implementation returns.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Action<SomeType, CallbackType> action = (__o1, __callback) =>
{
    __o1.Operation(__callback);
};
action.BeginInvoke(
    o1,
    callback,
    (asyncCallback) =>
    ((Action<SomeType, CallbackType>)((AsyncResult)asyncCallback).AsyncDelegate).EndInvoke(asyncCallback),
    action);
```